# Everything works but there is LAG in the script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tablesorter

I have a somewhat big piece of javascript/ajax code, and I would like to see if it is possible to make it run more efficiently WITHOUT taking out any functions.

My problem is that I'm getting a page called 'getlastupdate.php', it only has 14 numbers, these numbers are the date and time that a database table was last updated.

the format is:

- Year-Month-Day-HH-mm:ss

Here's an example: `20130724082105`

I took out the ':.-' because we don't need it.

My javascript code compares this with another ajax GET that repeatedly fetches the current date/time from 'getlastupdate.php'. If it finds that the two values are not the same it triggers another GET to fetch the row info.

It takes the updated row info and displays it in the browser. Finally it GETs the entire updated table and puts it back into the table (tablesorter).

Everything seems to work fine however I noticed some LAG when the script is adding the new table info and deleting the old ? or at least I think that is the main cause for the LAG.

Here is the code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tablesorter/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<!-- blue theme stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tablesorter/final/theme.blue.css">
<!-- tablesorter plugin -->
<script src="tablesorter/final/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<!-- tablesorter widget file - loaded after the plugin -->
<script src="tablesorter/final/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>


<!-- START: toastmessage Notify -->
    <link type="text/css" href="tablesorter/final/toastmessage/jquery.toastmessage-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/final/toastmessage/jquery.toastmessage-min.js"></script>
<!-- END: toastmessage Notify -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/qtip/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var comper;
function checkComper() {
var SvInfo;

  var onResponse = function(comperNow) {  // comperNow is the latest date/time var
    //check if comper has been set / first time method is called
    if (comper === undefined) {
      comper = comperNow;
      return;
    }

    if (comper !== comperNow) {


var Vinfoo;
$.get("getlastupdate2.php", function(primaryAddType){
//   alert("Data: " + primaryAddType);
   Vinfoo = primaryAddType;


// show a message to the visitor ----> 
//alert(Vinfoo);
  $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo);


 });
$('#append').trigger('click'); // UPDATE THE TABLE BUT IT TAKES 3-4 SEC. AND I NEED IT TO SPEED UP!

// and update comper to show the date/time from comperNow
comper = comperNow;
}
};
$.get('getlastupdate.php', onResponse);

}
var tid = setInterval(checkComper, 2000); // repeat myself

$(function() {

$('[title!=""]').qtip({}); // A bit better. Grab elements with a title attribute that isn't blank. <-- CUSTOM TOOLTIP

var $table = $("table.tablesorter");
$("#append").click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$.get('updatetable.php', function(data) 
{
$table
.find('tbody')
.html('')
.append(data);
$table.trigger("update", [true]);

$('[title!=""]').qtip({}); // A bit better. Grab elements with a title attribute that isn't blank. <-- CUSTOM TOOLTIP

});
});

  // call the tablesorter plugin
$("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',

    // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the change
    widthFixed : true,

    //sortList: [[2,0],[1,0]],

    // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
    widgets: ["saveSort", "zebra", "filter"],

//  headers: {  },

    widgetOptions : {

      // If there are child rows in the table (rows with class name from "cssChildRow" option)
      // and this option is true and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make that row
      // visible; default is false
      filter_childRows : false, 

      // if true, a filter will be added to the top of each table column;
      // disabled by using -> headers: { 1: { filter: false } } OR add class="filter-false"
      // if you set this to false, make sure you perform a search using the second method below
      filter_columnFilters : true,

      // css class applied to the table row containing the filters & the inputs within that row
      filter_cssFilter : 'tablesorter-filter',

      // class added to filtered rows (rows that are not showing); needed by pager plugin
      filter_filteredRow   : 'filtered',

      // add custom filter elements to the filter row
      // see the filter formatter demos for more specifics
      filter_formatter : null,

      // add custom filter functions using this option
      // see the filter widget custom demo for more specifics on how to use this option
      filter_functions : null,

      // if true, filters are collapsed initially, but can be revealed by hovering over the grey bar immediately
      // below the header row. Additionally, tabbing through the document will open the filter row when an input gets focus
      filter_hideFilters : false, // true, (see note in the options section above)

      // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
      filter_ignoreCase : true,

      // if true, search column content while the user types (with a delay)
      filter_liveSearch : true,

      // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
      filter_reset : 'button.reset',

      // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for
      // every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
      filter_searchDelay : 300,

      // if true, server-side filtering should be performed because client-side filtering will be disabled, but
      // the ui and events will still be used.
      filter_serversideFiltering: false,

      // Set this option to true to use the filter to find text from the start of the column
      // So typing in "a" will find "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
      filter_startsWith : false,

      // Filter using parsed content for ALL columns
      // be careful on using this on date columns as the date is parsed and stored as time in seconds
      filter_useParsedData : false

    }

  });

  // External search
  // buttons set up like this:
  // <button type="button" class="search" data-filter-column="4" data-filter-text="2?%">Saved Search</button>
  $('button.search').click(function(){
    /*** first method *** data-filter-column="1" data-filter-text="!son"
      add search value to Discount column (zero based index) input */
    var filters = [],
      col = $(this).data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
      txt = $(this).data('filter-text'); // text to add to filter

    filters[col] = txt;
    // using "table.hasFilters" here to make sure we aren't targetting a sticky header
    $.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table.hasFilters'), filters, true ); // new v2.9

    /** old method (prior to tablsorter v2.9 ***
    var filters = $('table.tablesorter').find('input.tablesorter-filter');
    filters.val(''); // clear all filters
    filters.eq(col).val(txt).trigger('search', false);
    ******/

    /*** second method ***
      this method bypasses the filter inputs, so the "filter_columnFilters"
      option can be set to false (no column filters showing)
    ******/
    /*
    var columns = [];
    columns[5] = '2?%'; // or define the array this way [ '', '', '', '', '', '2?%' ]
    $('table').trigger('search', [ columns ]);
    */

    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

I found the source of the LAG if I comment out this line:

```
$('#append').trigger('click'); // UPDATE THE TABLE BUT IT TAKES 3-4 SEC. AND I NEED IT TO SPEED UP! it will speed everything up but how do I get it to speed up or even slow down so that it doesn't lock up the current page.
```

What also speeds-up the loading is if I comment out this:

```
    var $table = $("table.tablesorter");
    $("#append").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get('updatetable.php', function(data) 
    {
    $table
    .find('tbody')
    .html('')
    .append(data);
    $table.trigger("update", [true]);

// ******** +++++++++++ **************    

    $('[title!=""]').qtip({}); // <-- CUSTOM TOOLTIP THIS SLOWS DOWN THE LOADING ALSO!!!!!

// ******** +++++++++++ **************    
    });
    });
```

@Abudoul Sy,
Here is what I have now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// I should be put at the top of the file (not in an Ajax Loop)
var compileHTML = function (html) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = html;
        var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        while ( div.firstChild ) {
            fragment.appendChild( div.firstChild );
        }
        return fragment
    };

var comper;
function checkComper() {
var SvInfo;

  var onResponse = function(comperNow) {  // comperNow is the latest date/time var
    //check if comper has been set / first time method is called
    if (comper === undefined) {
      comper = comperNow;
      return;
    }

    if (comper !== comperNow) {


var Vinfoo;
$.get("getlastupdate2.php", function(primaryAddType){
//   alert("Data: " + primaryAddType);
   Vinfoo = primaryAddType;


// show a message to the visitor ----> 
//alert(Vinfoo);
  $().toastmessage('showNoticeToast', Vinfoo);


 });
$('#append').trigger('click'); // UPDATE THE TABLE BUT IT TAKES 3-4 SEC. AND I NEED IT TO SPEED UP!

// and update comper to show the date/time from comperNow
comper = comperNow;
}
};
$.get('getlastupdate.php', onResponse);

}
var tid = setInterval(checkComper, 2000); // repeat myself

$(function() {

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('[title!=""]').qtip({}); // A bit better. Grab elements with a title attribute that isn't blank. <-- CUSTOM TOOLTIP
        })

var $table = $("table.tablesorter");
//Keeping a reference variable to 
var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody');


$("#append").click(function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$.get('updatetable.php', function(data) 
{
$table

 //When ajax is done
var compiledHtml = window.compileHTML(data); 
 $tableContents.html(compiledHTML);
 $table.trigger("update", [true]);


        $(document).ready(function()
        {
        $('[title!=""]').qtip({}); // A bit better. Grab elements with a title attribute that isn't blank. <-- CUSTOM TOOLTIP
        })

});
});

  // call the tablesorter plugin
$("table.tablesorter").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',

    // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the change
    widthFixed : true,

    //sortList: [[2,0],[1,0]],

    // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
    widgets: ["saveSort", "zebra", "filter"],

    headers: { 8: { sorter: false, filter: false } },

    widgetOptions : {

      // If there are child rows in the table (rows with class name from "cssChildRow" option)
      // and this option is true and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make that row
      // visible; default is false
      filter_childRows : false, 

      // if true, a filter will be added to the top of each table column;
      // disabled by using -> headers: { 1: { filter: false } } OR add class="filter-false"
      // if you set this to false, make sure you perform a search using the second method below
      filter_columnFilters : true,

      // css class applied to the table row containing the filters & the inputs within that row
      filter_cssFilter : 'tablesorter-filter',

      // class added to filtered rows (rows that are not showing); needed by pager plugin
      filter_filteredRow   : 'filtered',

      // add custom filter elements to the filter row
      // see the filter formatter demos for more specifics
      filter_formatter : null,

      // add custom filter functions using this option
      // see the filter widget custom demo for more specifics on how to use this option
      filter_functions : null,

      // if true, filters are collapsed initially, but can be revealed by hovering over the grey bar immediately
      // below the header row. Additionally, tabbing through the document will open the filter row when an input gets focus
      filter_hideFilters : false, // true, (see note in the options section above)

      // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
      filter_ignoreCase : true,

      // if true, search column content while the user types (with a delay)
      filter_liveSearch : true,

      // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
      filter_reset : 'button.reset',

      // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for
      // every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
      filter_searchDelay : 300,

      // if true, server-side filtering should be performed because client-side filtering will be disabled, but
      // the ui and events will still be used.
      filter_serversideFiltering: false,

      // Set this option to true to use the filter to find text from the start of the column
      // So typing in "a" will find "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
      filter_startsWith : false,

      // Filter using parsed content for ALL columns
      // be careful on using this on date columns as the date is parsed and stored as time in seconds
      filter_useParsedData : false

    }

  });

  // External search
  // buttons set up like this:
  // <button type="button" class="search" data-filter-column="4" data-filter-text="2?%">Saved Search</button>
  $('button.search').click(function(){
    /*** first method *** data-filter-column="1" data-filter-text="!son"
      add search value to Discount column (zero based index) input */
    var filters = [],
      col = $(this).data('filter-column'), // zero-based index
      txt = $(this).data('filter-text'); // text to add to filter

    filters[col] = txt;
    // using "table.hasFilters" here to make sure we aren't targetting a sticky header
    $.tablesorter.setFilters( $('table.hasFilters'), filters, true ); // new v2.9

    /** old method (prior to tablsorter v2.9 ***
    var filters = $('table.tablesorter').find('input.tablesorter-filter');
    filters.val(''); // clear all filters
    filters.eq(col).val(txt).trigger('search', false);
    ******/

    /*** second method ***
      this method bypasses the filter inputs, so the "filter_columnFilters"
      option can be set to false (no column filters showing)
    ******/
    /*
    var columns = [];
    columns[5] = '2?%'; // or define the array this way [ '', '', '', '', '', '2?%' ]
    $('table').trigger('search', [ columns ]);
    */

    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

Comment: how long is this *LAG* that you speak of? looking over your code, if you were to change the value in the table, i would expect a *delay* anywhere from 0ms to 3 seconds depending on where in the interval you were when the change was made and how fast the network is.

Comment: @KevinB WOW thanks for your super fast response!!! I found the source of what is causing the slow down it's in the code I updated the question so that it also notes this, I thought that it was all the GETs I was using but it's the adding and removing of the table info ? I don't mind it taking 3 or even 20 secs to get the updated/new info. I just don't want the page to lockup for anything more then 1 sec!

Comment: It looks like the lockup you're seeing is due to re-generating the table. How much data are you working with? I have a feeling this is going to be an issue that can only be fixed by either reducing the amount of data or going to a more efficient tablesorter. Also, `.html('').append(data)` can be replaced with `.html(data)`

Comment: @KevinB The size of the table info is 400-500KB (it's kinda big I think)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out your code:
Everytime you're doing an Ajax Request you're doing this:

```
$table
.find('tbody')
.html('')
.append(data);
$table.trigger("update", [true]);
```

To explain what it does :

1. you call `$.find` on a html tag (slow)
2. you remove the content of the table (causes the browser to repaint the pixels in white)
3. you ask the Browser's DOM to parse a whole html table causing multiple layout reprocessing and repaints (critically bad)
4. calling trigger on the table (ok)

I think that just by processing your data better can speed up your process countless times depending on the size of your table.
Consider this:

```
// I should be put at the top of the file (not in an Ajax Loop)
window.compileHTML = function (html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while ( div.firstChild ) {
        fragment.appendChild( div.firstChild );
    }
    return fragment
};
//Keeping a reference variable to 
var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')

//When ajax is done
var compiledHtml = window.compileHTML(data);
$tableContents.html(compiledHtml);
$table.trigger("update", [true]);
```

Edit: If `compileHTML` doesn't work.
A nice way of doing almost the same thing (but without compiling) would be to do:

```
//put just after $table declaration
var $tableContents = $table.find('tbody')

//When ajax is done
var $html = $('<tbody/>').html(data);
$tableContents.replaceWith($html)
$table.trigger("update", [true]);
```

Edit:

What I did was creating a document fragment (outside of DOM), let the html processing via `compileHTML` not have any incidence on the current page. And when all is done.
Appending only the root of the new dom tree created to the DOM, causing only one repaint against: "as many as there is cells and rows" will cause your browser to look more stable.

Optional (not totally):
There is probably more pitfalls on your code, but investigating performances is hard.
I would recommend doing a timeline check on [Chrome/Firebug](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) -> open console (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) press the "timeline" tab.
Press (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>cmd</kbd>)+<kbd>E</kbd> and let and update pass , repress <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and you'll see some histogram chart, the bigger bars mean your app is laggy/janky, you can then click on the bar to see the stack trace of all the function called and thus be optimized.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: WOW!! Thanks Abdoul! Even with that error the page loads 50% faster!!! I think it's because we wait for the document to be ready and then process qtip. but can you please look at the code again to see how I can fix the compiedHTML is undefined error! Thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging my answer :)
From what I've seen:
You should move $tableContents, just after $table = $("table.tablesorter"); is defined.
and because your handling of data is inside the callback of the ajax result
change var compileHTML by window.compileHTML = function
and in your results do: var compiledHtml = window.compileHTML(data);
That should do the trick :)

Comment: No Thank you very much!! :) Can you just please look at the code I have posted at the end of my question and see why I'm getting that compiedHTML is undefined error when it looks to me that it is defined?  THANKS A MILLION MY FRIEND!

Comment: Sorry I posted my comment to fast. I edited it with a plausible answer

Comment: I'm so sorry I did as you said but it's still giving me the same error, I have updated my question again to show you the latest code/update I have, can you please look at it again :( Thanks

Comment: :D No worries.
I see that you're calling window.compileHTML(data)
But In your update, you didn't change
the declaration of the function:
replace "var compileHTML = function" by "window.compileHTML =  function "

And also the variable names are not matching sorry For that I made A typo : replace "var compiledHtml = window.compileHTML(data); 
 $tableContents.html(compiledHTML);"

By "var compiledHtml = window.compileHTML(data); 
 $tableContents.html(compiledHtml );"
I'll edit my code.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I made the changes and the error is gone now but when the data is updated it changes the ?table format? It looks like it's loading the updated data into a single <TD> because I see all of the data but it's only inside the first <TD> on the left but when I copy and paste the source code into a editor and save it as .html and look at it again it formats correctly! ?

Comment: Unfortunately at some rare occations compileHTML doesn't work.
Sometimes it is when the html is not valid. sometimes it's because of the structure of the table.
Last chance for using compileHTML is maybe to include the tbody tag in the redered html from the ajax call and replacing the current tbody.
or, using jQuery do a $tableContents.html($('<tbody/>').addClass('someClassThatIWant').html(data));
-> that's not compiling the HTML, but that's still way faster than the other methods, as the way of adding HTML is the same as when compiled (outside the DOM).
Hope that helps

Comment: I wish I can get this to work but I just don't understand how to do what you suggested above, but you did help me so I will give you the answer and points, Thanks for everything, I will try to get it to work and if you find some free time and if you can help me some more and get this to work I would appreciate it, Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.
Sorry I wasn't that clear in the comment, Hard to be understandable in the comments. 
I'll publish an edit with the alternative solution in about 5'.

Answer (score 1):

I this the only conclusion is to make the output smaller in size then 400-500kb.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "loading... please wait" dialogue, just add something like:

```
<div id="loading_overlay" style="z-index:10000;background-color:#000;opacity:0.5;display:none;cursor:wait;">
    <div style="z-index:10001;background-color:#FFF;opacity:1;cursor:auto;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;height:300px;width:300px;margin-top:-150px;margin-left:-150px;">Please wait, loading...</div>
</div>
```

(Obviously, don't use inline styles in your actual document, put them in your external CSS file)

Then just before your `$.get('updatetable.php', function(data)` line add `$("#loading_overlay").show();`, then `$("#loading_overlay").hide();` after `$table.trigger("update", [true]);` (which I assume is the last line of your AJAX request).

Basically you show the loading dialogue just before the AJAX request, then hide it after it has completed.

This *doesn't* address the lag issue, but it does show a loading dialogue so the user knows why the browser has locked up (as you asked).